# Why do some angular commands use {{}}?

Tags: angularjs

What is the difference  between these two (why is one in {{}} and one in "")?

```
<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">

<img ng-src="{{store.product.images[0]}}" />
```

Oh, I think I see it now.  The Store controller as store is a function, and the store.product.images[0] is a string, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So why is the `ng-controller` directive different? Well, it's just down to how the *directives* (the `ng-xxx` bit) are written. It's possibly a bit in-depth for this answer, but it would be worth looking at how to create custom directives (see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), and how you can pass data parameters to them.

The difference comes down to how the `ng-controller` and `ng-src` directives expect their parameters.

When something is between `{{}}`, you can think of it as identifying to Angular that this attribute value needs to be *interpolated* before it is passed to the directive. Interpolation is a form of compiling placeholders in a string, and it is a string that `ng-src` is expecting to be passed. So to give it the string value for a product image, it needs to use the `{{}}`.

So in your example, `{{store.product.images[0]}}` may be interpolated (think *text replacement*) to something like `"\content\image1.jpg"`.

`ng-controller` will take care of parsing the value `StoreController as store` by itself, it's a syntax that only it knows about. As such, it just wants to read the attribute value as it is, with no preprocessing/interpolation.

I've simplified that a bit, but you can always check out more at  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate for a bit more detail.

I hope that makes sense and I haven't confused the issue.

Comment: I think I get it, essentially, directives have keywords/parameters/etc that it understands, such as ng-controller knows that if it gets something like 'PanelController as panel', as long as the syntax is correct, it can parse that.    In the case of ng-src, it needs a string but you can't put in the actual url sting because of the order in which the html is rendered, so you pass it the model path and wrap it in {{}} so when it si rendered, it knows that the stuff in the brackets has to be read at a certain time..